# Change PostgreSQL column type from money to double precision

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to change column data type in my PostreSQL 12.1 table from `money` to `double precision`.
I've tried this:

```
ALTER TABLE "tableName"
ALTER "price" TYPE double precision USING price::double precision,
ALTER "price" DROP DEFAULT,
ALTER "price" SET NOT NULL;
```

And I got this error:

> Error in query (7): ERROR: cannot cast type money to double precision at character 100

What's the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot cast directly from `money` to `double precision`.  First cast to `numeric`:

```
ALTER TABLE tableName
    ALTER price TYPE double precision USING price::numeric::double precision,
    ALTER price DROP DEFAULT,
    ALTER price SET NOT NULL;
```

This is actually explained in the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-money.html):

> Conversion from the real and double precision data types can be done by casting to numeric first, for example:

> .   SELECT '12.34'::float8::numeric::money;

Answer (score 0):

Try casting `money` to `numeric` first and then to `double precision` -

```
ALTER TABLE "tableName"
ALTER "price" TYPE double precision USING price::double precision,
ALTER "price" DROP DEFAULT,
ALTER "price" SET NOT NULL;
```